# Cannot Install Older Version of Rake Gem in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, rake

I have rake version 0.9.2 installed, and I think I need to install 0.8.7 to solve some problems. However, after installing 0.8.7, 0.9.2 is still installed. Here is what I ran:

```
rake --version
```

rake, version 0.9.2

```
gem install rake -v 0.8.7
```

Successfully installed rake-0.8.7
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for rake-0.8.7...
Installing RDoc documentation for rake-0.8.7...

I then added this to my Gemfile:

```
gem 'rake', '0.8.7'
```

But 0.9.2 is still called:

```
rake --version
```

rake, version 0.9.2

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Run this command on the bash:

```
gem uninstall rake
```

Then you will be asked which version you want to remove. You select 0.9.2 and then you run

```
bundle update rake
```

This should do it for you...

Comment: I ran the first command just fine, but I'm using Rails 2, and I read that I need version 3 to run bundle. How else can I accomplish this?

Comment: Ufff Im not sure. Try if it works already. When it doesnt you should hit the documentation of the gem command!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem (going back to a older version of rake in the Gemfile meant I got a "You have requested: rake = 10.3.2 ... The bundle currently has rake locked at 10.4.2." error). If "fixed" this by deleting the Gemfile.lock file and running bundle install like so:

```
rm Gemfile.lock
bundle
```

Now `rake --version` produces "rake, version 10.3.2"

This is an alternative to running `bundle update rake`.